# keep user logged in and logout successfully in android app sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to create a login activity which include navigation drawer
so how can i keep user logged in and logout successfully.

This is the login code

**MainAcitivity.java**

```
package com.example.takeattendence;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.takeattendence.database.LoginContract.LoginEntry;
import com.example.takeattendence.database.LoginDbHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private LoginDbHelper mLoginDbHelper;

    EditText emailEditText, passwordEditText;
    Button loginButton;
    TextView newAccountTextView;
    String EmailHolder, PasswordHolder;
    Boolean EditTextEmptyHolder;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    String TempPassword = "NOT_FOUND" ;
    public static final String UserEmail = "";
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        newAccountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_create_new_account_sign_in);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email_sign_in);
        passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_pass_sign_in);

        mLoginDbHelper = new LoginDbHelper(this);

        //Adding click listener to log in button.
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Calling EditText is empty or no method.
                CheckEditTextStatus();

                // Calling login method.
                LoginFunction();
            }
        });



        newAccountTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewAccount.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }




    // Checking EditText is empty or not.
    public void CheckEditTextStatus()
    {

        // Getting value from All EditText and storing into String Variables.
        EmailHolder = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        PasswordHolder = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

        // Checking EditText is empty or no using TextUtils.
        if( TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder))
        {

            EditTextEmptyHolder = false ;

        }
        else
        {
            EditTextEmptyHolder = true ;
        }
    }

    // Login function starts from here.
    public void LoginFunction()
    {

        if(EditTextEmptyHolder)
        {

            // Opening SQLite database write permission.
            db = mLoginDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            // Adding search email query to cursor.
            cursor = db.query(LoginEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, " " + LoginEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL_ID + "=?", new String[]{EmailHolder}, null, null, null);

            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {

                if (cursor.isFirst())
                {

                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    // Storing Password associated with entered email.
                    TempPassword = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LoginEntry.COLUMN_PASSWORD));

                    // Closing cursor.
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

            // Calling method to check final result ..
            CheckFinalResult();

        }
        else
        {

            //If any of login EditText empty then this block will be executed.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Enter UserName or Password.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }



    }

    // Checking entered password from SQLite database email associated password.
    public void CheckFinalResult()
    {

        if(TempPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(PasswordHolder))
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Going to Dashboard activity after login success message.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WelcomeApp.class);

            // Sending Email to Dashboard Activity using intent.
            intent.putExtra(UserEmail, EmailHolder);

            startActivity(intent);


        }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UserName or Password is Wrong, Please Try Again.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        TempPassword = "NOT_FOUND" ;
    }
  }
```

This is the navigation drawer code which including logout option
how can i logout successfully

**WelcomeApp.java**

```
package com.example.takeattendence;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class WelcomeApp extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_app);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.nav_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
       {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ProfileFragment()).commit();


            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_profile);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_update_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new UpdateProfileFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_see_database:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new StudenetInfoFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Intent in = new Intent(WelcomeApp.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();

                break;

            default:
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

I used sharepreference class but not get proper solution

Comment: Welcome to SO, actually there is no option to suggest you "ASAP". Please read these instructions from the link below before asking. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using shared preferences should do the trick....you can use it as below:

in login page (MainActivity.java) when user email password matches:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("email", emailVlaue);
editor.putString("password", passwordValue);
editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
//any other detail you want to save
editor.apply();
```

when you open this activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isLoggedIn= prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);

if(isLoggedIn){
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WelcomeApp.class)
    finish();
    return;
}
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
//your other codes
```

this will redirect user to WelcomeApp activity if they are logged in

to log out once the user clicks logOut button

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("password", "");
editor.putString("email", "");
editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
editor.apply();

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("finish", true);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);

finish();
```

Comment: i update code but i get error : error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to String

Comment: boolean isLoggedIn= prefs.getString("isLoggedIn", false); is changed to boolean isLoggedIn= prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false); i have edited the code please check

Comment: one problem is solve when i am a old user and login then the code give output correct but when i create account first time and goto my WelcomeApp.java activity. after that i closed my app and opened it again it returns me on login page. one more is that logout operation not successfully done.

Comment: what is the exact problem that you face on log out... can you please restate it.... for me a normal scenario is....user types user name and password...we check it with database...if success we redirect else show error....now if login is success and user closes and reopens the app...we do not ask for login and directly open the required page...if user logs out then redirect to login page...with this scenario which does not work for you??

Comment: when i pressed logout button it returns me same profile page

Comment: to solve your first problem...when you create account...you have to do the 1st shared preferences part again after successful account creation...to solve your log out problem.. you have to check if the value of isLoggedIn in shared preferences have changed or not.....you can do this by toast the value of boolean isLoggedIn....after if(isLoggedIn){ Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),isLoggedin+"",....).show();
//other code
}

Comment: i have edited the log out part code please change your code with this
please upvote and accept answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

to give an example for Kotlin since it didn't let me define like how unownsp said you can use this code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        val prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);
        var isLoggedIn = prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);

        if(isLoggedIn){
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(extraEmail, email)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
            return
        }
```

and everything else is like what unownsp said.just i used getApplicationContext to have access to sharedPreferences nothing special.